# Language Switch between browser tabs

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, joomla-3.3.x

I have a joomla site that enabled the arabic and english languages.The switching is working fine.

I have some clarifications.

1. First I open the english site and do the content change.
2. Then I open another tab in same browser and go to arabic site and do the content change while first tab remain in the previous english session.
3. Then if I go back to english tab and clicked a link,it automatically switch to arabic.

What I need is to keep both languages switch in different tabs.Can it be happen??

Please help.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible and also to be honest, is there much point? The whole point of a language switcher is you can view a website in the language you feel most comfortable with, therefore you choose your language at the beginning and it's set for your visit

Comment: Yes,that is true,but i need to know can be this done in joomla configuration or handle by coding or not possible what so ever?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't have different languages in different tabs.

In a multi-lingual Joomla website, the selected language is stored in a cookie, and the cookie lifetime can be set in the `Language Filter` plugin. The options are `Year` and `Session`:

[image: Multilingual Joomla lifetime cookie]

This means you can't have different languages i different tabs (within the same browser), because when you change languages, the settings will apply to all tabs in your browser.

The only way to have different languages active at the same time is to use two different browser, e.g. Firefox & Chrome.

You can change between browsers just as quickly as changing between tabs:
(<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> vs <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>).